# Stripe function cannot be found

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe in my angular7 application to handle payments via firebase cloud functions. I am currently trying to create a subscription payment. However, when I try and call the following function (as a sort of pre-req to the whole subscription setup);

```
import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('pk_test_....');

//Create payment method for customer
const {paymentMethod, createPaymentMethodError} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
    type: 'card',
    card: cardElementObj.card,
    billing_details: {
      name: userName,
      email: firebaseUserEmail
    },
  });
```

Error:

```
Property 'createPaymentMethod' does not exist on type 'Stripe'.
```

I have the stripe package installed in my node_modules (version 7.14.0).

package.json config:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tslint -p tslint.json && tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/stripe": "^7.13.11",
    "firebase": "^7.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "stripe": "^7.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/stripe-checkout": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/stripe-v3": "^3.1.9",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can probably help if you share some relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe doesn't provide a Typescript package, so you don't need those dependencies in your package.json to get it working. Instead:

First, make sure you have the script included on the page. Note that according to [their documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#including-stripejs), it must always be loaded from https://js.stripe.com/v3/.

Then, the Typescript code should be structured like so to get an instance of `Stripe` to use.

```js
declare var Stripe : any;

@Component({
  selector    : 'payment-form',
  templateUrl : 'payment-form.component.html',
})
export class PaymentFormComponent implements OnInit {
  stripe: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stripe = new Stripe(environment.stripeApiKey);
  }

  mySubmitFunction() {
    this.stripe.createPaymentMethod(...);
  }
}
```

This general structure of declaring the variable outside of the component definition is common when using Javascript libraries in Typescript. You'll have to follow similar steps when using the Facebook or Google OAuth libraries, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this as I am doing this in my app, however, my issue is that I am using cloud functions, and there is no index.html to be able to import this file in the method that Stripe specifies in their docs i.e. using script tags. How can I import it?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the limitation of Firebase Cloud functions, sorry. I found this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments) and [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe) that Google published for using Stripe with Firebase that you may find useful if you haven't seen already. Also, I see that you marked this as answered; was it really?

Comment: In a way it was, because I just decided to call these functions from the front end. There is no other way around it. One library is for the client side (i.e. the one with the createPaymentMethod function) and calling the APIs directly is for  the server side. So the solution is simple, perform this function from the client side. Thanks for your help :)